# Examples of uniform lattices - reference

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

Being interested in uniform lattices (that is, discrete co-compact subgroups) of connected Lie groups, I am searching for a literature with abundance of examples.

Comment: In the semisimple case: Dave Witte Morris, introduction to arithmetic groups: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063

Comment: The theory of uniform lattices in nilpotent groups (well, that's the only kind of lattices you may find there) appears in Raghunathan's book.

Comment: Crossposted and answered at MSE.